# Beginner Java Project Advice

Tags: java

I've never coded in Java before and I find that having an actual project sharpens the learning process.

So, I'm looking for some 'paint by number' code Java projects that are:

- for beginners
- online, and
- free.

It needs to be like Lego... for example there is a picture of what you will be creating, a description of the components, and step by step illustrated instructions how to complete the project.  And yes I've used Google, searched stackoverflow and even looked for cookbooks on Amazon but I can't seem to find what I'm after.

To put this question into context I am a beginner programmer who has done a little tinkering but wants to become much much better.  I started learning computer programming in Perl on Ubuntu but found it got too hard to quickly (bug finding difficult and very difficult to program web scraping) and I didn't find much help from the online Perl community to move my project forward (Perlmonks for example unless I paid someone to do when I wanted to learn how to do it myself).  My Perl code project was then abandoned and I didn't consider doing it in another language.  A year later I picked up AutoIt to overcome painful and repetitive IE tasks at work.  I got pretty far with AutoIt and found the community to be amazing and ready to help.  I ended up making a few different programs that I use every day at work.  I tried to extend to ever more complicated web-scraping and automation in AutoIt but found it broke with the release of IE9 and was extremely hard to program for when met with websites that used JavaScript extensively.  I looked at learning C# as a way of overcoming these limitations in AutoIt but found that I couldn't just jump into C# program IE automation tasks easily.  I was really inspired by a [video about being a data scientist](http://datascience101.wordpress.com/2012/05/02/the-first-ever-data-scientist/) and I'm now trying to learn Java with the view of completing the [free algorithms and machine learning courses online](http://www.coursera.org) and finally getting to grips with OOP.  I've tried starting these courses but find that an in-depth knowledge of Java is required.  I've made a start with a free Java course that covers the basics but find it hard to learn without a project to think about when learning the material.

Comment: First of all, step one has already been accomplished.  And, that is coming to a place like this.  I am a pro-programmer and I learned so much using stack overflow and experts-exchange.  I recommend starting small with a scripting language and graduating to a programming language.  But, you may be able to grasp the concepts of procedural programming, so if you can, just do that.

Comment: You know what I would personally do?  I would find a university website at which the computer science professors keep their Intro to Computer Science projects in a publicly accessible place, and use those as projects to work on as you learn the language.  

At the university that I attended, the ICS projects ramped up to be difficult exercises in thinking and logic, while not being too hard from the standpoint of the language, and they were interesting enough to keep people who were taking the course for something other than computer science to remain interested.

Comment: You don't need to start a big Java project. Sometimes you can start with very simple Java projects like those at end of chapters in most Java books. And Java has a larger API than most languages so be prepared to sweat it out. Good luck !

Comment: @user1477388: Thanks for the reply. I did start with scripting... Perl and AutoIt.  I love the AutoIt syntax and its über helpful community but I need more 'grunt' in a programming language thus the direction in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Work your way up to java.

Start here http://w3schools.com and learn everything HTML/JavaScript/Php etc related. Then take on java.

Although if youre convinced you want to start on java then download the netbeans IDE and go through their tutorials. They are pretty good.  [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org)

Comment: Just something you should know before you go off advising beginners : http://w3fools.com/

Comment: I know w3schools isnt perfect but it does give a very simple environment for basic development to understand basic principles.

Comment: @Quinma: thank you for your advice, I do know of w3schools and wanted to avoid learning HTML/JavaScript/Php first since I felt that this would be a lot of ground work with no useful application for me.

Comment: @Kazekage Gaara: Naruto fan are we?  Thanks for the link to w3fools.com idk about it and found its suggested path and links to be useful.  If I go with the suggestion to 'work my way up' to Java I'll start there.

Answer (score 0):

To start with Java, i would recommend you one of the How to Program books from Deitel, the code is fully explained and pretty clear, and they include a exercises and full project that can be accomplished while you advance on the book.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend that you get a *very* strong pre-Java foundation before diving into Java.  Reason being, Java is just not an easy first language for picking up the logic and general concepts - the syntax can be tough. Check the Khan Academy's videos .

Do that for about a month, then start Java coding, work through the sun tutorials. Aim to program at least 5 minutes a day(like, outside of the tutorials). 10 minutes will happen often.

Answer (score 0):

I used [JavaBat](http://javabat.com), now known as [CodingBat](http://codingbat.com), when I was first learning Java. It's intended for beginners, free, and online. Perhaps you can start with String-1's helloName and build up from there. I would use it alongside other resources, but it is a good way to practice different concepts.